# Linux - check speed of a network

Tags: linux, networking, network-speed

Does anybody know which command I can use in my Linux console, to check what the speed of the network of a costumer is?
I have the network IP and gateway, is there anything I can do to perform a line check to see what the up and Down speed is with a Linux command?

Comment: please could you clarify what it is you want to measure. Is it the overall network performance of that customer's box, and do you have access to it?, or are you on the recieving end somehow? What network do you want to measure, ie between what endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

Try iperf. You need 2 machines.

- a server: `iperf -s`
- a client: `iperf -c IP-OF-THE-SERVER`

You have many options with iperf. See its manpage for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I use speedtest's cli

to install it:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest_cli.py

chmod a+rx speedtest_cli.py

sudo mv speedtest_cli.py /usr/local/bin/speedtest-cli

sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/speedtest-cli
```

then you can use the "speedtest-cli" command to start the test and if you use: "speedtest-cli --share" then you'll get a link to share the result.

Comment: as a remark, out of the box, `speedtest-cli` can only be used to test public Internet network speeds against public servers hosted by developer Ookla or other providers. The previously additionally provided *Speedtest Mini* for hosting your own Speedtest server to test against (e.g. for local LAN network speed tests) isn't available since 2017. https://www.speedtest.net/mini

Answer (score 0):

testing the download speed is usually quite easy, just download a big file with curl and see the speed column.

if you need upload speeds as well, there is a nice python script called 'tespeed':

https://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test

Answer (score 0):

In order to test upload ou migh as well store the following code at any website, call it from a form and call it from a curl command:

```
<?php
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
 else
{
$start = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$end=  time();
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
echo "Time:" . ($end - $start) . "<br>";
}

    if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/a/path/you/set/for/upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) ) {
        echo "Stored in: " ." /a/path/you/set/for/upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
else {
echo "Could not save the file";
}
```

curl --form file=@test.img  --form submit=submit http://your.website.com

Answer (score 0):

For the network link speed, just use `ethtool [interface-name]`.

You will see the "Speed:" and many other details.